# error on boost filesystem

Tags: boost, filesystems

I try to use boost filesystem on my Mac. I only added the following header and got an error when I tried to compile

```
# include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

the error is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in cclyDZox.o
"boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in cclyDZox.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Haven't you forgotten the flags -lboost_system and -lboost_filesystem when linking?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the boost_system library:

```
-lboost_system
```

to your build command. Note that you will also need to provide the -lboost_system library too.

If your project thereafter builds but moans with something like

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_filesystem.dylib
```

you just need to set the environment variable

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to include your

```
$BOOST_HOME/lib
```

directory as mentioned [here](http://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/how-to-solve-linker-dependencies-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do

```
g++ -I~/Documents/boost_1_53_0/include -L~/Documents/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib -std=c++11 test1ver1.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

The

- `-I` flag points to where the Boost headers are
- `-L` flag points to where the Boost libs are
- `-lboost_filesystem` and `-lboost_system` flags enabled the link of your binary and the Boost Filesystem and System shared libraries. (Those should be always after the object or source files)

For instance:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
   boost::filesystem::path path_household_csv("./test");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did as you said and I still got the same error                                                               ld: library not found for -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: did I miss something? I am stocked - I appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, try with `-L~/Documents/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib` instead of -L~/Documents/boost_1_53_0/`. I corrected my answer.

Comment: thank you, it is compiled. however, at runtime it gives me the following error  dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib  Referenced from: ~/Desktop/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap                                                             Can you help me to figure out the reason

Comment: I found it, export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Documents/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/

Comment: I don't know very well the OSX platform. However after googling your error, there is maybe one solution. [http://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/how-to-solve-linker-dependencies-on-mac-os-x/]( potential solution/) run `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Documents/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib` before running the ./a.out - check also the [http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Aug/msg00174.html](extensive explanation solution)

Comment: Thank you, I just saw your comments. The problem is solved. I truly appreciate your time.