# boost::filesystem Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, boost, g++

I am very new with using GNU. I am trying to start using the boost filesystem library, and I keep getting these errors. I am trying to get the current working directory, by using `boost::filesystem`.

My code:

```
boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::detail::current_path() );
cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << endl;
```

My command:

```
g++ -I boost_1_58_0 main.cpp -o example
```

Result:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-1c56eb.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main-1c56eb.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main-1c56eb.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main-1c56eb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Can someone please explain what the error is asking for? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost.filesystem` is not a header-only library. You have to link to the library using `-L` and `-l` flags. (And make sure the library is already properly built). You need to link to both `boost_system` and `boost_filesystem` libraries. 
The command line could look like:

```
g++ -Iboost_1_58_0 -Lboost_1_58_0/lib/ -lboost-filesystem -lboost_system main.cpp -o example
```

(replace the `-L` argument with the path where the `libboost-filesystem.so` file resides)

Then, before you are able run the executable, you have to let the loader know where to look for the libraries. You shell be able do that using the following command:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost/bib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

To make it automatic, I would recommend using a build system like [`cmake`](http://cmake.org) instead of just a command line.

Comment: This command worked and produced an .exe file. `g++ -I boost_1_58_0 -Lboost_1_58_0/lib/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system main.cpp -o example`. However when I run the .exe file I get an error: `dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_filesystem.dylib`

Comment: Found someone with the exact same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189999/error-on-boost-filesystem

Comment: You shall also specify a path to the library for runtime loading. In linux it is `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running your program. On MacOS it can be a bit different, I don't know exactly.

Comment: Looks like it is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on OSX. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is equal to the path where `boost_1_58_0/lib/` is located I checked to confirm using: `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and I can confirm `libboost_filesystem.dylib` resides in that location. But yet I still get the same error? `dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_filesystem.dylib`